# is it possible to make all fields of an object @Transient by default

Tags: java, persistence, jpa-2.0

I have a base Entity class which will be derived in more than a hundred of a subclasses.

In order to be sure that persisted fields will be the ones I want (and not the users of that base class), I want to declare this JPA entity as setting all fields as transient by default.

How is it possible ?

Comment: As far as I'm aware JPA assumes all ﬁelds are persistent by default, so you have to use @Transient on a field by field basis.  I know of no way to override the default.

Comment: I guess you could look at creating a View of your Entity which gets persisted and then instantiating your Entity with a copy constructor.  So on Entity call getPersistentState which returns the PersistentEntity to save to the datastore, then when you read it back create the Entity by passing in the PersistentEntity returned from the datastore. If you're not owning the Base Class it sounds like this might be a good option as your persistence would always be tied to the unowned superclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't put @MappedSuperclass on your class you are extending from, the class properties will never by persisted.
You can provide getter methods for certain properties, and place the annotations on the properties instead of the fields. The @Id annotation determines if you want the fields or the properties. In JPA 2 you can also use the @Access annotation.